# How to access JSON array in Java?

Tags: java, json

I need to get `elementId` from my JSON file which is shown below:

```
{
    "intents": [{
        "type": "PathIntent",
        "id": "0x0",
        "appId": "org.onosproject.cli",
        "resources": ["DefaultLink{src=ConnectPoint{elementId=00:00:00:00:00:01/-1, portNumber=0}, dst=ConnectPoint{elementId=of:0000000000000003, portNumber=1}, type=EDGE, state=ACTIVE, durable=false}", "DefaultLink{src=ConnectPoint{elementId=of:0000000000000003, portNumber=3}, dst=ConnectPoint{elementId=of:0000000000000002, portNumber=1}, type=DIRECT, state=ACTIVE, durable=false}", "DefaultLink{src=ConnectPoint{elementId=of:0000000000000002, portNumber=2}, dst=ConnectPoint{elementId=of:0000000000000004, portNumber=3}, type=DIRECT, state=ACTIVE, durable=false}", "DefaultLink{src=ConnectPoint{elementId=of:0000000000000004, portNumber=2}, dst=ConnectPoint{elementId=00:00:00:00:00:04/-1, portNumber=0}, type=EDGE, state=ACTIVE, durable=false}"],
        "state": "INSTALLED"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Which parser are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you'll find some tips to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an JSON-Array is very easy:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("...");
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("resources");
```

You will get an array of this elements

```
"DefaultLink{src=ConnectPoint{elementId=00:00:00:00:00:01/-1, portNumber=0}, dst=ConnectPoint{elementId=of:0000000000000003, portNumber=1}, type=EDGE, state=ACTIVE, durable=false}"
```

Unfortunately you need to parse the String i guess.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I parsed the string and got that.